# Error "Could not locate a bind configured on mapper" for SQLAlchemy and pylons

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here to warrant this message.  Any help with my configuration would be appreciated.

```
"""The application's model objects"""
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

from project.model import meta

def now():
    return datetime.datetime.now()

def init_model(engine):
    """Call me before using any of the tables or classes in the model"""
    sm = orm.sessionmaker(autoflush=True, autocommit=True, bind=engine)
    meta.Session.configure(bind=engine)
    meta.engine = engine
    meta.Session = orm.scoped_session(sm)

class User(object):
    pass

t_user = sa.Table("User", meta.metadata,
sa.Column("id", sa.types.Integer, primary_key=True),
sa.Column("name", sa.types.String(100), nullable=False),
sa.Column("first_name", sa.types.String(100), nullable=False),
sa.Column("last_name", sa.types.String(100), nullable=False),
sa.Column("email", sa.types.String(100), nullable=False),
sa.Column("password", sa.types.String(32), nullable=False)
)

orm.mapper(User,t_user)
```

From the python console, I am executing:

```
from project.model import *

mr_jones = User()
meta.Session.add(mr_jones)
mr_jones.name = 'JR Jones'
meta.Session.commit()
```

And the error I receive is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper Mapper|User|User or this Session
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was resolved.  I didn't know that when using pylons from the CLI, I have to include the entire environment:

```
from paste.deploy import appconfig
from pylons import config

from project.config.environment import load_environment

conf = appconfig('config:development.ini', relative_to='.')
load_environment(conf.global_conf, conf.local_conf)

from project.model import *
```

After this the database queries executed without a problem.

Comment: What's name of `project.config.environment` module, if i want to install it via `pip` or `distribuition packages`?